if H and H' are isomorphic in a finite group G, is it always possible to find an automorphism of G that sends H to H'?
As the title.
If $H$ and $H^\prime$ are isomorphic in a finite group $G$, is it always possible to find an automorphism of $G$ that sends $H$ to $H^\prime$?

Notice that, when the subgroups are normal, such an automorphism induces an isomorphism of the quotient groups. Hence this is answered by the duplicates.

Just $C_2\times C_4$ has two subgroups of order $2,$ generated by $ (1,0)$ and $(0,2),$ and no such automorphism exists.
